# Get Exact calculated total Hours and minutes in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Good day. Im using ms sql server 2005 express and heres my table structure:

```
      User  |        Log_Date         |     Log_In_Time         |       Log_Out_Time      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    xxx     | 2013-10-02 23:00:31.623 | 2013-10-02 23:07:31.623 | 2013-10-03 01:08:31.623 |
```

**NOTE:**

**LOG_OUT_TIME** is in other day which is **October 3, 1:08 AM**, **LOG_IN_TIME** is **October 2, 11:00 PM**

Now I want to add **column:**  **TOTAL**

and it look like this:

```
      User  |        Log_Date         |     Log_In_Time         |       Log_Out_Time      | TOTAL  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    xxx     | 2013-10-02 23:00:31.623 | 2013-10-02 23:07:31.623 | 2013-10-03 01:08:31.623 | 2.08   |
```

Can anybody know the way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you expect `2.08` this is just hours, do you want it in minutes as well (eg 2 hours 1 minute or 2:01)?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple way:

```
CAST(Log_Out_Time - Log_In_Time AS TIME)
```

Gives:

```
02:01:00.0000000
```

**Edit:**

Exact query:

```
DECLARE @ST DATETIME = '2013-10-02 23:07:31.623'
DECLARE @ET DATETIME = '2013-10-03 01:08:31.623'

SELECT CAST(@ET - @ST AS TIME)
```

Comment: I tried this in sql-server i'm getting the following error : Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator. ? could you give the exact query ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi I've added the exact code, as far as I know this will only work in SQL Server 2008 and later.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, Log_In_Time, Log_Out_Time) AS varchar) + '.' + 
    CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, Log_In_Time, Log_Out_Time) / (60 * DATEDIFF(hour, Log_In_Time, Log_Out_Time) ) AS varchar)
FROM tableName
```

I have calculated the hours and minutes separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateDiff @Unknownymous, what I would do is seconds comparison, cast this to a float and the divide by 60 as necessary. This will give you minutes, hours, etc scaling up to the precision you need.

```
DECLARE @diff float
DECLARE @diffMin float
DECLARE @diffHour float
DECLARE @diffDay float

SELECT @diff = cast(datediff(ss,Log_in_Time,Log_Out_Time) as FLOAT)
SELECT @diffMin = @diff/60
SELECT @diffHour = @diffMin/60
SELECT @diffDay = @diffHour/24

print @diff
print @diffmin
print @diffhour
print @diffday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
cast(datepart(hour,Log_Out_Time - Log_Date) as varchar) + '.' +  
right('00' + cast(datepart(minute,Log_Out_Time - Log_Date) as varchar),2)
```